# JavaScript to include external HTML is working in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, include, html-imports

The script that I am using to import external HTML which has my Bootstrap based Navbar, here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');

// Clone the <template> in the import.
var template = link.import.querySelector('template');

var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

document.querySelector('#navBar').appendChild(clone);

</script>
```

In my HTML page, all I am doing is including a reference to external html file in  section and adding a div in my  section with defined class name as follows:

```
<!— link of external HTML file in <HEAD> section -->
<link rel="import" href="navbar.html">

<!— Div with defined class name “navBar”in <BODY> section -->
<div id="navBar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5? Internet Exploder?
https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Nope.

Can use a polyfill like this though:
https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports

Answer (score 1):

Only the Chrome browser supports HTML imports. You should use a [polyfill](https://github.com/AshleyScirra/html-imports-polyfill) for different browsers.